# Image flipping using JQuery issue

Tags: jquery, image, flip

I am flipping an image on the click event. At first click, the second image is displayed (after first gets flipped) but it is not working vice versa.

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var margin = $("#image1").width() / 2;
        var width = $("#image1").width();
        var height = $("#image1").height();

        $("#image2").stop().css({ width: '0px', height: '' + height + 'px', marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px', opacity: '0.5' });
        $("#reflection2").stop().css({ width: '0px', height: '' + height + 'px', marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px' });

        $("#image1").click(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '0px', height: '' + height + 'px', marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px', opacity: '0.5' }, { duration: 300 });
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $("#image2").stop().animate({ width: '' + width + 'px', height: '' + height + 'px', marginLeft: '0px', opacity: '1' }, { duration: 300 });
            }, 500);
        });

        $("#image2").click(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: '0px', height: '' + height + 'px', marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px', opacity: '0.5' }, { duration: 500 });
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $("#image1").stop().animate({ width: '' + width + 'px', height: '' + height + 'px', marginLeft: '0px', opacity: '1' }, { duration: 500 });
            }, 500);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Would you make an jsFiddle for this? Would make it alot easier to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Fiddle : [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WJWmh/)

Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes.Actually i had a spelling mistake for image id.